# Support MS Office 2010 x64 in Windows Sever 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, office-2010

Does is support the Ms Office x64 in Windows Server R2 Enterprise? I need some links.

Comment: Windows Server R2 Enterprise support the Ms Office x64

Answer (score 2):

Office 2010 is supported on 2008 R2:

[Office 2010 System Requirements](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/microsoft-office-2010-system-requirements-HA101810407.aspx)